# I'm getting an error when trying to get my method to examine the argument

Tags: java, boolean

I have to get my method to read if the string has spaces and if it does it goes to the next step which is to see if the string has letters or numbers 1 through 5 in the string.

Here is what is stated in the directions: This method should examine its argument to see if it has a space in positions 5, 11, 17, 23 and so on, and if it consists of letters and the digits 1 though 5 in all other positions. If this is the case it should return true, otherwise return false.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Enc1.java:41: error: no suitable method found for length(int)
            if(s.indexOf(s.length(i)) == -1 || i > 5 || i < 1)
                          ^
    method CharSequence.length() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method String.length() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Enc1
{
    public static  void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c1 = args[0];
        System.out.println("Please insert a word: ");
        c1 = stdin.next();
        isCoded(c1);

    } // end main

    private static final String CODE1 = "HTNZUL5m3lDQchenpIuORws1jPgVtzKWbfBxXSArdayCJkvqGiF2YoM4E" ;

    private static final String PLAIN = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,.;:" ;

    public static String encode(String message)
    {
        System.out.println("encode called");
        return message;

    } // end encode

    public static String decode(String codedMessage)
    {
        System.out.println("decode called");
        return codedMessage;

    } // end decode

    public static boolean isCoded(String s)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) 
        {
            if( i % 6 == 5 && s.charAt(i) != ' ')  
              return false;
            if(s.indexOf(s.length(i)) == -1 || i > 5 || i < 1)
              return false; 
        }


    } // end isCoded 

} // end Enc1
```

Comment: The error message is telling you **exactly** what's wrong -- the length method does not take a parameter -- so do the obvious solution and fix it: get rid of the erroneous call. Why are you using length there anyway? Don't you want to use `charAt(...)` or something similar?

Comment: charAt worked thank you.

Comment: Bottom line: read the error messages critically. They're not cryptic and will usually tell you exactly what's wrong and where.

Comment: These two errors are the only errors? Because there are more errors in the `isCoded` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you exactly what's wrong -- the length method does not take a parameter -- so do the obvious solution and fix it: get rid of the erroneous call.

Change

```
if(s.indexOf(s.length(i)) == -1 || i > 5 || i < 1)
```

to

```
if(s.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1 || i > 5 || i < 1)
```